# DDD: Passing parameters to domain entity methods with app config/env variable values

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Question about right approach to application design in DDD:

Client asked to set request status to 'Expired' after 10 days. Do I hardcode the value in the Request entity in the IsRequestExpired() method (Domain layer) like so:

```cs
public bool IsRequestExpired(DateTime now) 
{
    int daysToSetExpiredStatus = 10;
    return Created <= now.AddDays(-daysToSetExpiredStatus);
}
```

This seems to have the following drawbacks:

- not easy to test by manual tester (needs to wait 10 days for result?)
- in case business decides the value should now be 20 we need to modify existing code

A solution would to both would be passing a value from application settings/env variables, like so:

```cs
public bool IsRequestExpired(DateTime now, in daysToSetToExpiredStatus) 
{
    return Created <= now.AddDays(-daysToSetExpiredStatus);
}
```

but is this still considered in line with DDD, as the invariant (expire after 10 days) is not really included in the Request entity (or the Domain layer whatsoever) any more but is fetched from config?

Answer (score 2):

> is this still considered in line with DDD

Absolutely!  In particular, it's not usually the responsibility of the "domain model" to decide where information comes from (reading from databases, or files, or the internet, or whatever is normally code you want in the application layer, not in the domain layer).

Comment: Fully agree to @VoiceOfUnreason's answer, you can consider the business logic in the domain layer as some decision making authority. The application layer makes sure the domain layer gets all the information needed, then the domain layer applies business logic and makes the decision and passes it back to the application layer. Either via return values, domain events, etc. It's then up to the application layer to act upon this decision to incur the respective side effects to the "outside world".